# sum of a range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

say , I have a data like below in one sheet,

```
Name        Date    time 1   time 2  time 3 time 4  
DA_BAB      02/11/2019   6        1       0      1
DA_GMO      02/11/2019   4        3       5      0 
            02/11/2019   1        2       1      1 
DA_GMO      02/11/2019   2        1       1      4 
Lloyd       02/11/2019   0        2       0      0
```

I had to group according to name and sum all the time under one category in vba .

eg DA_BAB  is 8 and Lloyd is 2 and so on.

I am really new to vba and do not know how to write this .Could anyone help me?

I tried to create a function and call that function, but it did not work

when we group data we should get like below

DA_BAB  is 8 and Lloyd is 2 and so on.

Comment: And the blank line, to whom does it go?

Comment: So you're summing up, per row, and outputting on the far right (adjacent to *time 4*)?   For *DA_GMO* do you only care about the individual rows (12 & 8), or for that date would it be combined (20)?  Are you allowed to use helper columns?  Is VBA a requirement, or are you able to just use formula in the sheet?

Comment: Hi Ciril,    Thanks for your reply....as you stated, I am planning to add a column next to time 4 . For output of DA_GMO,it should be sum of all 3 rows ,that's 25. yes I am allowed to use ,helper columns.   It should be done only using vba code.

Comment: Add a column that has no blanks for the names and use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

If your data is laid out between columns A to F, then the following code will give you the Summary in Column I & J, this will give you your desired results.

I've now added a statement to use the previous Name if one of the rows doesn't actually contain anything:

```
Sub Combine()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
'loop through column A to get unique Names
    If c.Value = "" Then
    'if value is empty then use previous value
        Valu = ws.Cells(c.Row - 1, "A").Value
    Else
        Valu = c.Value
    End If

    Set FoundVal = ws.Range("I:I").Find(What:=Valu, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    'see if name already exists in Column I
    If FoundVal Is Nothing Then
    'if name not found
        newRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'get the next free row on column I
        ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = c.Value
        'add new name
        ws.Cells(newRow, "J").Value = ws.Cells(newRow, "J").Value + ws.Cells(c.Row, "C").Value + ws.Cells(c.Row, "D").Value + ws.Cells(c.Row, "E").Value + ws.Cells(c.Row, "F").Value
        'add new name
    Else
        ws.Cells(FoundVal.Row, "J").Value = ws.Cells(FoundVal.Row, "J").Value + ws.Cells(FoundVal.Row, "C").Value + ws.Cells(FoundVal.Row, "D").Value + ws.Cells(c.Row, "E").Value + ws.Cells(FoundVal.Row, "F").Value
    End If
Next
ws.Range("I1").Value = "Name"
ws.Range("J1").Value = "Totals"
End Sub
```